# Boost.Spirit.Qi: How to report parser warnings?

Tags: c++, parsing, warnings, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

How to report parser warnings?
Similar to reporting error, but the parser must not stop. 
Only log warning message and the subexpression caused the warning.

Example input:

```
 select * from table where row>='' && row<>'hello'
```

Expected output:

```
 Warning: expression is always true: row>=''
 Warning: && is deprecated, use AND: row>='' && row<>'hello'
 Warning: <> is deprecated, use !=: row<>'hello'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to continue parsing you can register an error handler as before, except that you have to specify `accept` as the handlers policy:

```
rule<Iterator> r = ... > !eps;
on_error<accept>(r, handler);
```

The appended `> !eps` forces the error in any case and invokes the `handler` as usual, but it will accept the match after the 'error', continuing as if nothing happened.

Comment: thanks! is there any way to get the current iterator in semantic action without assigning _pass=false, raising on_error and then continue parsing? it seems to be simpler just to print warnings from semantic action code but I found to way how to obtain there the input iterator (or, better, the iterator range of the currently parsed expression) in order to include the excerpt from input text into the warning message.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/creating-your-own-parser-component-for-spirit-qi/ ?